# possible to generate a dynamic variable?

Tags: python, function, variables, multiprocessing

I want to call a function, that starts a subprocess, like that:

```
processrrd = Popen(args1, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, env={'LANG':'de_DE@euro','TZ':'Europe/Berlin'})
outputrrd = processrrd.communicate()
(output, error) = outputrrd
```

Now I want to use multiprocessing.pool in order to paralize the worker.
The problem is that the variable outputrrd ist overwritten by the last Popen.
So, is it possible to create a specific variable (processrrd), like name1_processrrd?

Regards.
Stefan

UDPATE:
tried this one, but the output of the processes are the same....:

```
processrrd = []
processrrd.append((hostgroup+'_processrrd'))
print processrrd
    for name in processrrd:
        print name
        name = Popen(args1, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, env={'LANG':'de_DE@euro','TZ':'Europe/Berlin'})
        outputrrd = name.communicate()
    (output, error) = outputrrd
```

Comment: Generating variables at runtime is possible, but discouraged. Use a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without even considering whether `multiprocessing` gives you any better approaches (I'm guessing it does, but don't know it very well at all), you'd be better off storing each handle in some sort of data structure, such as a `dict` or a `list`, e.g.,

```
# TODO Use name and key that works for you.
my_processes['de_DE@euro'] = Popen(args1, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, env={'LANG':'de_DE@euro','TZ':'Europe/Berlin'})
```